# Which NoSQL database is best to store chat messages?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, erlang, cassandra, cassandra-cli

I am working in mobile chat application using ejabberd as server and mysql as main database to store user's details. I want to store chat messages in NoSQL database for fast retrieval and avoid traffic.Each conversation should be in single key.There are different NoSQl databases like Hbase, Cassandra, Riak,MongoDB, Redis. But don't know that which one to choose.So please suggest right one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your userbase is relatively small, you should probably stick with MySQL. Switching to NoSQL will not provide a noticeable performance increase, and you will end up having to learn a new paradigm for no reason.
If learning is your goal though, I'd recommend MongoDB. I feel this one is the easiest to grasp.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with Erlang and relational DB like Mnesia you can use it. Ejabberd uses Mnesia but recommends MySQL for large datasets. If the requirement is to store the data in a NoSQL DB, then probably Riak or MongoDB would be a better choice.